# Django not accepting data from python-requests.patch()

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I'm trying to send data from a service running with python through a http `PATCH` request to another running Django with [Django API Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/).

The `SomeAccount` has a field `appUserId` which is now `-1`.

Here is the **some_sender.py** who knows about the `app_user_id` (`=77`, e.g.):

```
auth = ('someusrname', 'somepwd')
data = {"appUserId": app_user_id}
url = 'myapi:8000/someaccounts/1'
r = requests.patch(url, data=data, auth=auth)
print r.status_code
#> 200
```

When I check the value of the item at `GET /someaccounts/1` it still has `appUserId=-1`.

While debugging, in Django I get the request, but without any data - it's just an empty dict.

Here is how I it looks in Django:

**mysite/myapp/urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'someaccount', views.SomeAccountViewSet)
# ...
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    # ...
]
```

**mysite/myapp/models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
# ...
class SomeAccount(models.Model):
    """
    Some account can include all the data related to some user's account.
    """
    # ...
    appUserId = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**mysite/myapp/views.py**:

```
class SomeAccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows some accounts to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = SomeAccount.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SomeAccountSerializer
```

**mysite/myapp/serializers.py**:

```
from models import SomeAccount
# ...
class SomeAccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = SomeAccount
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'appUserId')
        depth = 3
        partial = True

    def update(self, someAccount, account_data):
        if 'appUserId' in account_data:
            someAccount.appUserId = account_data.pop('appUserId')
        someAccount.save()
        return someAccount
```

In `SomeAccountSerializer` when debugging on the incoming request I get the following values:

- `account_data: {}`
- `initial_data: <QueryDict: {}>`
- `someAccount: {'appUserId': -1, 'id': 1}`

I tried to send the same values through the Postman Google Chrome plugin and it worked.

I also tried to set the `content-type` header:

with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
requests.patch(
    url, data=data, auth=auth,
    headers={'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
)
```

with `application/form-data`:

```
requests.patch(
    url, data=data, auth=auth,
    headers={'content-type': 'application/form-data'}
)
```

with `application/json`:

```
requests.patch(
    url, json=json.dumps(data), auth=auth,
    headers={'content-type': 'application/json'}
)
```

without being successful.

EDIT:
python-requests is sending the request correctly. The problem probably lies in how Django is handling it.

Comment: Check the response body from requests, maybe that has some insight into the issue.

Comment: This also helped, thanks! Turned out there where some errors on the server side and the URL (I probably was also missing a `/` at the end of the url string. So it should've been `GET /someaccounts/1/`)

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this same issue. Was missing the trailing slash on the URL. When Django redirected to the URL with the trailing slash, it seemed to drop the payload of the PATCH.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your network traffic to make sure where the problem appears. If I use

```
import requests

app_user_id = 7
auth = ('someusrname', 'somepwd')
data = {'appUserId': app_user_id}
url = 'http://localhost:8000/someaccounts/1'

r = requests.put(url, data=data, auth=auth)
print r.status_code
```

and open a local socket with netcat (nc -l 8000) I am getting the data form encoded:

```
PUT /someaccounts/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Content-Length: 11
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.8.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Basic c29tZXVzcm5hbWU6c29tZXB3ZA==

appUserId=7
```

Comment: OK, same here. It appears that it is still sending the data. (Only diff: `User-Agent: python-requests/2.6.0 CPython/2.7.10 Darwin/14.5.0`)